# Sum with Exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've got the following sum which I'm trying to figure out:

$$\sum_{x=0}^n 2^{-x}$$

Wolframalpha tells me that it's equal to $2 - 2^{-n}$ but I am interested in figuring out why, and how to get that result by hand.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Also, as you can tell, I could really use some help with MathJax...

Comment: ^ "covers" only the following element, so if you write, say, x^yz only the $y$ will be in exponent, and the same is true for 2^-x. You want 2^{-x}.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) with first term $1$ and common ratio $1/2$.

There is a [well-known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for calculating such sums.

Your sum, $S$ is given by:

$$S = \frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n}$$

This is a geometric series because to get from one term to the next we multiply the the common ratio $\frac{1}{2}$. The usual trick for geometric series is to multiply $S$ by the common ratio:

$$\frac{1}{2}S = \frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

Taking the difference between $S$ and $\frac{1}{2}S$ gives us:
$$S-\frac{1}{2}S = \frac{1}{2^0}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

Obviously $S-\frac{1}{2}S=\frac{1}{2}S$ and $\frac{1}{2^0}=\frac{1}{1}=1$. The last line the becomes
$$\frac{1}{2}S=1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$
Finally, we multiply both sides by $2$ to get $S$:

$$S=2-\frac{2}{2^{n+1}} = 2-\frac{1}{2^n} = 2-2^{-n} $$

Comment: It's a geometric series? Doesn't the summation symbol mean it's an arithmetic series, since we're adding $2^{-n}$ each time?

Comment: @GuiR No. *Both* geometric series and arithmetic series are given by adding things up; that's what series means. $1+3+5+7+9$ is an arithmetic series because there is a *common difference*: $3-1=2$, $5-3=2$, $7-5=2$ and $9-7=2$. On the other hand $1+2+4+8+16$ is a geometric series because there is a *common ratio*: $2\div 1 = 2$, $4\div 2 = 2$, $8 \div 4 = 2$ and $16 \div 8 = 2$.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, that makes perfect sense! I tried doing it that way:

$S_n = a*\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$, where $r=2^{-1}$ and $a=2^0=1$

$S_n = 1*\frac{1-(2^{-1})^n}{1-2^-1} = \frac{1-(2^{-1})^n}{0.5}$

$S_n = 2*(1-2^{-n})$

However, when I multiply this:

$S_n = 2 - 2*2^{-n} = 2 - 2^{1-n}$

Can you spot my mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've updated my answer. You made a mistake with the formula. Because you start from $x=0$ and go up to $x=n$ you have $n+1$ terms and not $n$. The correct expression is below. **Don't forget to click the up arrow for helpful answers and clicking the tick for the best answer.**

$$S = a\left(\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\right)$$

Comment: I used the formula in the wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Geometric_series) and checked in a couple books I have, which say the same thing.. :/

Comment: @GuiR Like I said: the formula is for the sum that has $n$ terms. You have $n+1$ terms. Usually we start with $x=1$ but you start with $x=0$ so you have an extra term. If the first term is $a$, the common ratio is $r$ and there are $t$ terms then:

$$S_t = a\left(\frac{1-r^t}{1-r}\right)$$

*However*, you have $n+1$ terms, so $t=n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
S_{n} \equiv \sum_{x = 0}^{n}2^{-x} = \half\sum_{x = 0}^{n}2^{-x + 1}
= \half\sum_{x = -1}^{n - 1}2^{-x}
= \half\pars{\sum_{x = 0}^{n}2^{-x} + 2 - 2^{-n}}
=\half\,S_{n} + 1 - 2^{-n - 1}
$$
Then,
$$
\half\,S_{n} = 1 - 2^{-n - 1}\quad\imp\quad
\color{#0000ff}{\large S_{n}} = 2\pars{1 - 2^{-n - 1}}
= \color{#0000ff}{\large 2 - 2^{-n}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $$\displaystyle S=\sum_{x=0}^n 2^{-x}$$ then $$\displaystyle  2S=\sum_{x=0}^n 2^{1-x} = \sum_{x=-1}^{n-1} 2^{-x}$$ and subtracting the former from the latter gives the result

Comment: How do you know $\sum_{x=0}^n 2^{1-x} = \sum_{x=-1}^{n-1} 2^{-x}$ ?
I understand the $x=-1$ part, but wouldn't not "extending" the number of items in the series effectively make $2S=S$? (not saying it isn't true, just that... it isn't clear from that work)

Comment: Slightly more detail . . . If $ \displaystyle  2S=\sum_{x=0}^n 2^{1-x}$ then let $y=x-1$.  So: $1-x=-y$ in general; in particular $y=-1$ when $x=0$, and $y=n-1$ when $x=n$.  So $\displaystyle   2S   = \sum_{y=-1}^{n-1} 2^{-y}$.  Now replace $y$ by $x$ and $\displaystyle   2S   = \sum_{x=-1}^{n-1} 2^{-x}$.